# Hide the content div underneath the fixed div while scrolling

Tags: html, css

- **.shadow-box** div used as a fixed header containing logos and 2 button.
- **.rest** div used for content and should go underneath the header while scrolling.

Right now when the page is scrolled the content from the **.rest** div is scrolled and is overlapping with the fixed header represented by the **.shadow-box** div;

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'halfmoon'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('halfmoon_regular.woff'); /*URL to font*/
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'halfmoon_b'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('halfmoon_bold.woff'); /*URL to font*/
}

body{
  margin:0px;
}

.shadow-box{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d0d4d9;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #d0d4d9;
  text-align:center;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.shadow-box .github-img{
  position: absolute;;
  top:7px;
  left: 315px;
  margin:13px auto
  background:  #000;
}

.shadow-box img{
  display: inline-block;
  margin:13px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.shadow-box .button-link{
  position: absolute;;
  padding:7px 16px;
  top:20px;
  right: 335px;
  border:1px solid #006DF0;
  border-radius:10px;
  color: #006DF0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:inherit;
  font-family: halfmoon_b, sans-serif;
}

.shadow-box .github-link{
  position: absolute;
  padding:7px 16px;
  top:20px;
  left: 335px;
  color: #006DF0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:inherit;
  font-family: halfmoon_b, sans-serif;
}

.rest{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
  text-align:center;
  height:800px;
  top:60px;
  width:100%;
  z-index:5;
  padding-top:20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.rest h1{
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 250%;
  color: rgb(100,100,100);
  font-family: halfmoon, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title>CloudBox</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/g3.ico" />
 <!-- <script src="js/script.js"></script> -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/index.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <div class="shadow-box">
    <a href="https://github.com/alexifrim95/CloudBox" id="git-img" class="github-img"><img src="img/GitHub-Mark-32px.png" alt="github-logo" class="github-logo"></a>
    <a href="https://github.com/alexifrim95/CloudBox" id="git-link" class="github-link">GitHub link</a>
    <img src="img/g3.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo-text.png" alt="logo-text" class=logo-text">
    <a href="#" id="sign-in" class="button-link">Sign in</a>
  </div>

  <div class="rest" >
    <h1>Cloud platform built<br>from scratch</h1>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your fixed div `.shadow-box` is transparent.
Add some background to it.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'halfmoon'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('halfmoon_regular.woff'); /*URL to font*/
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'halfmoon_b'; /*a name to be used later*/
    src: url('halfmoon_bold.woff'); /*URL to font*/
}

body{
  margin:0px;
}

.shadow-box{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d0d4d9;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #d0d4d9;
  text-align:center;
  overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
}


.shadow-box .github-img{
  position: absolute;;
  top:7px;
  left: 315px;
  margin:13px auto
  background:  #000;
}

.shadow-box img{
  display: inline-block;
  margin:13px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.shadow-box .button-link{
  position: absolute;;
  padding:7px 16px;
  top:20px;
  right: 335px;
  border:1px solid #006DF0;
  border-radius:10px;
  color: #006DF0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:inherit;
  font-family: halfmoon_b, sans-serif;
}

.shadow-box .github-link{
  position: absolute;
  padding:7px 16px;
  top:20px;
  left: 335px;
  color: #006DF0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:inherit;
  font-family: halfmoon_b, sans-serif;
}

.rest{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
  text-align:center;
  height:800px;
  top:60px;
  width:100%;
  z-index:5;
  padding-top:20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.rest h1{
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 250%;
  color: rgb(100,100,100);
  font-family: halfmoon, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset=utf-8 />
 <title>CloudBox</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/g3.ico" />
 <!-- <script src="js/script.js"></script> -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/index.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <div class="shadow-box">
    <a href="https://github.com/alexifrim95/CloudBox" id="git-img" class="github-img"><img src="img/GitHub-Mark-32px.png" alt="github-logo" class="github-logo"></a>
    <a href="https://github.com/alexifrim95/CloudBox" id="git-link" class="github-link">GitHub link</a>
    <img src="img/g3.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo-text.png" alt="logo-text" class=logo-text">
    <a href="#" id="sign-in" class="button-link">Sign in</a>
  </div>

  <div class="rest" >
    <h1>Cloud platform built<br>from scratch</h1>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @pol you hae no idea how much this problem was bugging me for hours.

Answer (score 0):

if you want that your nav be transparent :

1- add your background-color in body : body{ background-color: rgb(250,250,250);}

or 
2- remove this code from .rest {top: 60px;} and increase margin-top: 70px;